The position of adverbs

Where do we put adverbs of frequency in a passive continuous sentence?

I am always doing your work- your work is (always) being (always) done (always) by me

what about ly adverbs?

I am carefully counting money- money is (carefully) being (carefully) counted (carefully)

The passive versions are so unlikely it's not even worth bothering to think about the position of the adverb. And for active utterances, carefully normally comes after the primary verb - for example, it's almost always I'm listening carefully, not I'm carefully listening.

"your work is always being done by me" does not mean the same as "I am always doing your work". "Always" has different scope in each (even aside from its weaker informal meanings).


The most natural sounding version is


Your work is always being done by me.

I doubt if you would hear a native speaker use any of the alternatives.

In this particular context all three versions are acceptable and may be used by a native speaker.


money is carefully being counted.
money is being carefully counted.
money is being counted carefully.

I think the second version would probably be the most likely, but I don't think there's a hard and fast rule about it. There is no difference in meaning to any of them.
===
Later
I've found a useful article just by searching for "position of adverbs in English". It seems pretty comprehensive and better than my answer. That search will give you several more similar articles which may help you.

Jenings Could I say "money is being counted by me carefully"?

@marta You could say that and be understood by any English speaker, but it's not a common construct, the adverb sounds as if it's been tagged on the end as an afterthought.

@marta See the link I've added to my answer.

Yeah thanks I know that site but there's nothing about passive

Two practical thoughts: (1) You are asking where to place an adverb. An adverb by definition qualifies a verb. So if you are not sure, place it next to the verb. Your example sounds not quite right because of the separation. (2) You are right that the linked article shows only active sentences, not passive. There's a reason for that, and you should learn from it. I would almost always say I counted the money rather than The money was counted by me.


I am always doing your work.

You have to put the adverb after the verb 'be'

Your work is always being done by me.


I am carefully counting money.


Money is carefully being counted by me.

