The placement of adverbs
My book states that adverbs such as "weekly, daily, monthly" should be placed at the end. For instance,

We take care of that issue daily

Would you accept placing it at the beginning?

Daily, we take care of that issue


It might be acceptable in 'literary' language, but it would be odd in ordinary, practical writing or speech.

You asked a very similar question 10 days ago https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/360168/the-position-of-adverbs/360170#360170 . I mentioned a link to a site you already knew about https://www.espressoenglish.net/position-of-adverbs-in-english-sentences/  which has a section on "Adverbs of time & frequency". Does none of that help?

It's emphatic putting it at the start. For instance if you wanted to contrast things that were daily and weekly, you might say "Daily, we make the beds. Weekly, we wash the bed linen." (Although even then you might prefer "Every day..."

You tend to ask questions in which you ask if you can use a particular structure of grammar. This is rather backwards! The is communication, not using grammar.  Correct grammar is how you can improve communication. Here, you know well a correct way to place the adjective: "at the end".  Why not just use that? Why worry whether you can accept an alternative You can don't need to put the adverb at the start.#

@JamesK Sorry to point this out, but you might consider proof reading your comment. For example "The is communication"  and "You can don't need"
